# How to Create a Text Editor in Flutter that Generates Different Text Formats Based on User Styling Preferences?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, pub.dev

I'm working on a Flutter application and need a text editor functionality that allows users to perform basic text formatting (e.g., bold, italic) and generate text output based on different platforms or formats.

The requirements include:

1. A text editor interface within the Flutter app that enables users to format text (e.g., bold, italicize, etc.).
2. Capability to convert the formatted text into various output formats suitable for different platforms (e.g., HTML, WhatsApp, etc.).
3. For example, if the user applies formatting such as bolding a word, the output for HTML should be "<strong>Bold Word</strong>", while for WhatsApp, it should be "*Bold Word*".

I've explored various text editing libraries in Flutter but haven't found a straightforward way to achieve this text formatting and output conversion based on different platforms.

Could anyone guide me on how to implement a text editor that provides these features? Are there any specific libraries, packages, or methods within Flutter that can help in achieving this functionality efficiently?

Any examples, code snippets, or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: You can use [flutter_quill](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill/example) package

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`flutter_quill`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill) package.

import library as

```
import 'package:flutter_quill/flutter_quill.dart' as quill;
```

make controller

```
  quill.QuillController _controller = quill.QuillController.basic();
```

and use it as

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Text Editor'),
      ),
      body: quill.QuillEditor(
        controller: _controller,
        readOnly: false,
        autoFocus: true,
      ),
    );
```

Use functions like this to achieve functionality

```
String formattedText = _controller.document.toPlainText();
String htmlOutput = convertToHTML(formattedText);
String whatsappOutput = convertToWhatsApp(formattedText);
```

Please define these functions according to your requirements